# Play audio using button and restart to the beginning when the button is clicked again

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making several button that if I clicked it plays designated sounds each button, and stop the sounds if I clicked another button and plays that sound. And if I click again the button, the sound will repeat to the beginning. Thanks :)

```
javascript 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#menuIcon').mouseover(function(e) {
    $('.bar1').addClass("hovered");
    $('.bar2').addClass("hovered");
    $('.bar3').addClass("hovered");
  });
  $('#menuIcon').mouseout(function () {
    $(".bar1").removeClass("hovered");
    $(".bar2").removeClass("hovered");
    $(".bar3").removeClass("hovered");
  });



  });

  function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
  }


  function playSound() {
    var sound= new Audio('sound campaign/10,000 Reasons.mp3');
   sound.currentTime = 0
        sound.play();
    }
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="10,000 Reasons" onclick="playSound()" />
```

Comment: So you mean Pause the audio and continue from where stopped?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, what I mean is, if I clicked the button it will play designated sound from it, and when I clicked other button, the playing sound stop while the new sound will play from the newly clicked button, and if I clicked the button that already playing, the sound will start from the beginning. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the sound.pause(); to pause it.
If you would like to use multiple audios, you should use the HTML audio tag.
It would allow you to pause all of them at once.

example:

```
<input type="button" value="10,000 Reasons" onclick="playSound(0)" />

<audio src="sound campaign/10,000 Reasons.mp3" autoplay loop>
</audio>
```

```
function playSound(e) {
 var sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  for(i=0; i<sounds.length; i++) sounds[i].pause();
 var sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[e];

   sound.currentTime = 0
        sound.play();
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, I will try this at home :)